# Portable electron app is extracted in a different folder every time it opens

Tags: javascript, socket.io, electron, firewall, electron-builder

- **electron-builder version**: 20.9.2
- **Target**: windows/portable

---

I'm building a portable app with [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) and using [socket.io](https://socket.io/) to keep a real-time connection with a backend service but I have an issue with the firewall. Because this is a portable app everytime the app is opened it looks that it is extracted in the temporary folder, which will generate a new folder (so the path to the app will be different) in every run which will make the firewall think that this is another app asking for the connection permissions. How can I change the extraction path when I run the app?

(This is the screen that I get every time I run the app)
[image]

This is my socket.io configuration

```
const io = require("socket.io")(6524);

io.on("connect", socket => {
    socket.on("notification", data => {
       EventBus.$emit("notifications", JSON.parse(data));
   });
});
```

My build settings in `package.json`

```
"build": {
    "productName": "xxx",
    "appId": "xxx.xxx.xxx",
    "directories": {
        "output": "build"
    },
    "files": [
        "dist/electron/**/*",
        "!**/node_modules/*/{CHANGELOG.md,README.md,README,readme.md,readme,test,__tests__,tests,powered-test,example,examples,*.d.ts}",
        "!**/node_modules/.bin",
        "!**/*.{o,hprof,orig,pyc,pyo,rbc}",
        "!**/._*",
        "!**/{.DS_Store,.git,.hg,.svn,CVS,RCS,SCCS,__pycache__,thumbs.db,.gitignore,.gitattributes,.editorconfig,.flowconfig,.yarn-metadata.json,.idea,appveyor.yml,.travis.yml,circle.yml,npm-debug.log,.nyc_output,yarn.lock,.yarn-integrity}",
        "!**/node_modules/search-index/si${/*}"
    ],
    "win": {
        "icon": "build/icons/myicon.ico",
        "target": "portable"
    }
},
```

Any idea about how at least I could specify an extraction path or make this extract it the execution folder?

---

BTW I already created an [issue](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/2909) about this in the electron-builder repo

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this? We are having the exact same issue.

Comment: @AleksandarGrbic nope, we had to get rid of the portable build due of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In version `20.40.1` they added a new configuration key `unpackDirName`

```
/**
   * The unpack directory name in [TEMP](https://www.askvg.com/where-does-windows-store-temporary-files-and-how-to-change-temp-folder-location/) directory.
   *
   * Defaults to [uuid](https://github.com/segmentio/ksuid) of build (changed on each build of portable executable).
   */
  readonly unpackDirName?: string
```

Example

```
config: {
  portable: {
    unpackDirName: "0ujssxh0cECutqzMgbtXSGnjorm",
  }
}
```

More info [#3799](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3799#issuecomment-480185505).